# purpose of class template

Tags: c++

I am reviewing a code where there is a number of classes inheriting from a single class template:

```
class BILL : public nulled<BILL>
{
...
}
```

where nulled<> is defined as:

```
template<class type> class nulled {
public:
    nulled () {
        int offset = int ((nulled<type>*) this) - int ((type*) this);
        ZeroMemory ((nulled<type>*) this, sizeof (type) - offset);
    }
};
```

2 questions: 
i) why using an inheritance like this ?
ii) how to interpret the subtraction shown for offset ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Read about the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: Also, the title for this question is vague. Please edit it with something future question askers could find.

Comment: `BILL` does **not** inherit from a class template. It inherits from an **instance** of a class template. A template is a pattern for creating classes; it is not a class. If you muddle the two you'll find yourself deeply confused at some time in the near future.

Comment: Some programmer dude, thanks for your link !

Comment: Bill, thanks for your conceptual clarification !